# Hibernate code generation: org.hibernate.HibernateException: 'hibernate.dialect' must be set when no Connection available

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, code-generation, dialect

I got this problem when trying to use Hibernate Tool Code generation in Eclipse Mars. I have Dialect in my `hibernate.cfg.xml` already, `sqljdbc4.jar` included.

> org.hibernate.HibernateException: 'hibernate.dialect' 
>       enter code here must be set when no Connection available

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
                                         "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory name="">
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password">123</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=Qlsach</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">sa</property>
  <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property>
 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**hibernate.reveng.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-reverse-engineering PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Reverse Engineering DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-reverse-engineering-3.0.dtd" >

<hibernate-reverse-engineering>
  <table-filter match-catalog="QLSACH" match-schema="dbo" match-name="DanhMuc"/>
  <table-filter match-catalog="QLSACH" match-schema="dbo" match-name="sach"/>
</hibernate-reverse-engineering>
```

Comment: How did u try to create the Session factory? Can you add that code here?

Comment: I didn't create Session factory yet. I just create the project, create the cfg.xml, reveng.xml and try to generate the POJO class and mapping xml file. I do this job perfectly in NetBeans but not in Eclipse.

Comment: where do you specify reveng.xml in eclipse mars ? i couldnt find where i can add it

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by changing Hibernate version from 5.1 to 4.3 in "Main" tab of Hibernate configuration dialog.

Comment: Solved similar problem by specifying "Type: core" in Project / Hibernate settings.